# Attribute weighted KMeans

Tags: machine-learning, k-means

I'm trying to use Kmeans clustering, with an intent to find out clusters by weighting the attributes.

Eg. if attribute A matters less than attribute B then the output should put more weight on values of attribute B and if needed give me more clusters depending on relatively small differences in B, even if this means ignoring relatively bigger differences in values of attribute A.

Any pointers/references/examples are highly appreciated.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/77850/3277

Answer (score 1):

Since the clusters are determined using the distance function, use a distance function that adds weight to required features and conversely, reduced weights on other features.

I suggest that you can start by using a weight of 1 for the required features and ignore the rest of the features. The choice of distance function itself , such as Euclidean or Manhattan, is orthogonal to the feature weighting.